# Avoid wxPython TextCtrl differences between macOS and Windows

Tags: python, wxpython

This simple snippet for a text control produces significantly different results on macOS (top) and Windows with wxPython 4.0.4. How can I mitigate that?

```
self.console_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.HSCROLL)
self.console_ctrl.SetFont(wx.Font(13, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL))
self.console_ctrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
self.console_ctrl.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
self.console_ctrl.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
```

[image: wxPython TextCtrl on macOS]

[image: wxPython TextCtrl on Windows 10]

The font on Windows seems much larger. Never mind the bad screen shot quality; must be related to Windows running in VirtualBox.

Note: this was cross-posted to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/j3HFo_-SeaU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventually decisive improvement was to define the font with pixels rather than points.

```
self.console_ctrl.SetFont(wx.Font((0, 13), wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL))
```

Note how the first parameter to the (overloaded) [`wx.Font` constructor](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Font.html#wx.Font.__init__) is now a `wx.Size` rather than an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indetify the OS in your code and setup the correct font for each one, check wxPython Demo for examples